# JSPX scriplet inside HTML input type textbox

Tags: jspx, scriptlet

I have the following in my jspx file:

```
<jsp:scriplet>
   int myvar = 2;
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

How can I put variable myvar into a textbox (id=myinput) value using JSTL or scriptlet (I can do this using session variable)

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="...the value of myvar..."/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it really necessary to use scriptlet? You can do this using JSTL.

Comment: I want an answer for JSTL, not scriptlet. I had better make this clear in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="<%=myvar%>"/>
```

Comment: This does not work because it's a JSPX file, not JSP. Sorry it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little typo in previous answer. Please use like this

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="<%=myvar%>"/>
```